# Understanding method for disproving uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

One way to disprove uniform convergence of a series of functions $f_n(x)$ in a domain D is to find the maximum of $f_n(x)$ at the domain and then to show that this maximum is bigger than an epsilon bigger than zero. This negates the definition of uniform convergence.

But sometimes there is no maximum of $f_n(x)$ in the domain. In this example : [Show $\frac{\ln{(1+nx^2)}}{2n}$ is not uniform convergent on $[0,\infty)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349395/show-frac-ln1nx22n-is-not-uniform-convergent-on-0-infty) the user chooses $x= e^n$, then $f_n(e^n) \gt 1$ and if we choose $\epsilon = 1 $ then we are done. The same goes with an answer of a question I made : [The uniform convergence of a series of functions depends on the domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4366202/the-uniform-convergence-of-a-series-of-functions-depends-on-the-domain)

Now, my question is : How do I know the value of x? What is the trick? Unfortunately, the users did not go into detail on how they choose that particular x. And I cant understand it. I will appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Comment: There are no specific tricks... now, since for all $n$, you have that $\ln(1+nx^2)\to \infty $ when $x\to \infty $, then for all $n\in\mathbb N$, there is $x_n>0$ s.t. $\ln(1+nx_n^2)>2n$, and thus $f_n(x_n)>1$ for all $n$... no need to exhibit a specific $x_n$, it's just important to know that such $x_n$ exist.

Comment: The trick is: understand how $f_n$ behaves, in particular if it is bounded. If you see that the function is not bounded, the supremum is $+\infty$ and there is no hope of uniform convergence to a bounded function.